# Shortest way to get last element by class name in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I know that by using `jQuery` you can easily use `:last` selector to get the last element.

```
$(".some-element:last")
```

Although, this does **not** work with javascript.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".some-element:last")
```

What would be the best and shortest way to do the same thing in `javascript`?

Comment: try `:last-child`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Take a look at the [Selectors Overview](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#overview)

> **E:last-child**
>
> *an E element, last child of its parent*

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".some-element:last-child"))
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="some-element">1</li>
  <li class="some-element">2</li>
  <li class="some-element">3</li>
</ul>
```

**--Update--**

If you have additional elements that do not share the same class name you can try a different approach like using

> **E:nth-last-of-type(n)**
>
> *an E element, the n-th sibling of its type, counting from the last one*

```js
var lastLiItem = document.querySelectorAll("li:nth-last-of-type(1)");
var lastSomeElement = document.querySelectorAll("li:nth-last-of-type(2)");

console.log("This is the last li item in the list: ", lastLiItem[0]);
console.log("This is the last li item with class .some-element in the list: ", lastSomeElement[0]);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="some-element">1</li>
  <li class="some-element">2</li>
  <li class="some-element">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Or to only get the last element with class of `.some-element`simply do

```
var someElementsItems = document.querySelectorAll(".some-element");
console.log(someElementsItems[someElementsItems.length -1])
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work if you put an element at the end, that does not have that class name. For example-   `... <li class="some-element">3</li><li>4</li>`. In this case, the value is `undefined`.Other than that, nice sample.

Comment: The second paragraph is completely unnecessary since it doesn’t look for class names.

Answer (score 11):

`querySelectorAll` returns `NodeList` object which can be converted to `Array`. Then `pop` returns the last element.

### ES2015 / ES6:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.some-element')).pop();
```

#### Demo:

```js
function addItem(withClass){
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', withClass
    ? '<div class="some-element">with class</div>'
    : '<div>without class</div>'
  )
  
  findLastOfClass('.some-element')
}

function findLastOfClass(selector){
  var lastOfClass = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].pop()
  
  // temporarily highlight last-of-class
  if( lastOfClass ){
    lastOfClass.classList.add('highlight')
    setTimeout(()=> lastOfClass.classList.remove('highlight'), 1000)
  }
}
```

```css
.highlight{ background: lightyellow }
```

```html
<button onClick="addItem(true)">add item with class</button>
<button onClick="addItem()">add item without class</button>
```

---

### Older browsers (IE8+):

```js
Array.prototype.pop.call(document.querySelectorAll('.some-element'));
```

Comment: sorry but this is just wrong... querySelectorAll if you want just one last item? it's expensive...

Comment: @Kepro `querySelectorAll` selects all elements and `pop` returns the last one. It is not wrong, unless you have better idea how to achieve the goal (don't hesitate to add your answer). Keep in mind the question: "Shortest way to get...".

Answer (score 5):

To find the last child of an element you can use this:

```
var childrenCount = document.getElementById("myDIV").childNodes.length;
document.getElementById("myDIV").childNodes[childrenCount-1];
```

Comment: `length != lastIndex`

Answer (score 4):

**Follow these Steps**:

1. Find All Element: `var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".some-element");`
2. Find Length: `var len = elems.length;`
3. Get Last Element: `var lastelement = len < 1 ? "" : elems[len-1];`