# javascript copy text from div to input

Tags: javascript, html

i was just wondering if there is anyway i could copy text from a div with same class name into an input field

i am trying to copy text from the last div with same class name then paste into input field how could i do this?

```html
<div class="message">TEXT HERE</div>

<div class="message">TEXT HERE</div>

<div class="message">COPY THIS TEXT TO INPUT</div>

<div id="input_box" class="td_input">
<input type="text" name="content" id="content">
</div>
```

sorry for my bad english

Comment: `i am trying` Yes, there might be a way, have you tried anything at all yourself yet? Please post the code

Comment: Break it apart into steps and you should be able to research yourself towards an answer quite easily! **(1)** [Get the last element of a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223343/shortest-way-to-get-last-element-by-class-name-in-javascript) **(2)** [Get the text from that element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370204/how-can-get-the-text-of-a-div-tag-using-only-javascript-no-jquery) **(3)** [Populate the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700471/set-value-of-input-using-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After select all div message Use `nodes[nodes.length- 1]` for last div

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.message');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];
document.querySelector('#content').value =last.innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="message">TEXT HERE</div>

<div class="message">TEXT HERE</div>

<div class="message">COPY THIS TEXT TO INPUT</div>

<div id="input_box" class="td_input">
<input type="text" name="content" id="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the getElementsByClassName already select the last node?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using jquery:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var value = $(".message").last().text();
document.getElementById('content').value = value
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="message">TEXT HERE</div>

    <div class="message">TEXT HERE</div>

    <div class="message">COPY THIS TEXT TO INPUT</div>

    <div id="input_box" class="td_input">
    <input type="text" name="content" id="content">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("message");
var lastElem = elems[elems.length - 1];
document.getElementById("content").value = lastElem.innerText;
```