# Select last element contained in a certain element by class?

Tags: javascript, chartist.js

I have tried solutions found in similar questions regarding Javascript, however, none of those solutions have worked. The script still continues to target ALL of the elements instead of just the last one. Below I have included my last attempt to get this to work. I have a chart with an id of "mainChart" and inside that chart, there is a "ct-series-b" element that contains "ct-bar" elements. I need to target the last "ct-bar" element contained within "ct-series-b" each time the script is run. How can I do this?

I have tried all of these solutions: [Shortest way to get last element by class name in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223343/shortest-way-to-get-last-element-by-class-name-in-javascript) and at best, it still targets all of the "ct-bar" elements.

JS

```
            const Chart = document.getElementById("mainChart");
            const series = Chart.querySelectorAll('.ct-series-b > .ct-bar')
            var last = Chart.querySelectorAll('.ct-series-b > .ct-bar:nth-last-of-type(1)')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:last-child` selector. Note that this will get the last `.ct-bar` under *each* `.ct-series-b`, so if you only wanted it under one of them you could adjust the query.

```js
const Chart = document.getElementById("mainChart");
const last = Chart.querySelectorAll('.ct-series-b > .ct-bar:last-child')

console.log(last[0].textContent);
console.log(last[1].textContent);
```

```html
<div id="mainChart">
  <div class="ct-series-b">
    <div class="ct-bar">1</div>
    <div class="ct-bar">2</div>
    <div class="ct-bar">3</div>
    <div class="ct-bar">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="ct-series-b">
    <div class="ct-bar">5</div>
    <div class="ct-bar">6</div>
    <div class="ct-bar">7</div>
    <div class="ct-bar">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, @Nick. Sadly, I tried this selector earlier too and it still keeps targeting all of the ct-bar elements contained in the ct-series-b element. It should work, I know. :(

Comment: If you run my code snippet it's definitely just selecting the last one isn't it?

Comment: I'm wondering if your DOM hierarchy isn't what you necessarily think it is? Maybe past it in the question?

Comment: Yes, your code snippet works. It's just that when I try to apply that solution in the app, it's not working. I am guessing maybe something funky it going on with Chartist, perhaps. I am able to target all of the ct-bar elements just fine using the selector without anything more specific, but if I try to target a particular ct-bar element, that is where it stops behaving properly.

Comment: I just took a look at the HTML again in the inspector and yes, it's rendering as I described it here. So the solution you posted should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a for loop to get it to do what I wanted. Now it properly labels each bar in the chart.

JS

```
var series = Chart.querySelectorAll('.ct-series-b > .ct-bar')

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                var seriesLabel = data.labels[i]
                                $(series[i]).attr("ct:info", seriesLabel)
                            }
```